# How in Flex to load cached preloaded images

Tags: apache-flex, image, caching, preload

In my application, I make numerous calls to preload images to brower cache in the background using Loader instances and ignore the complete event. I don't store the results in the application, but rather want to store them in the browser cache. The images have long Expires header dates.

When I want to use a particular image(s), I again use a Loader instance and call the same url and listen for the complete event to load the file to an Image.

The problem is that when I re-request the url for the "cached" image, it is making an http request with response 200 status, which I presume means it is hitting the server.

How do I make sure that a request for a cached image never hits the server from Flex?

In general, I am finding that any request to a url for a cached image (with a long expires header) is making another request to the server, or at least that is my interpretation of it in Firebug.

Any ideas how to do this? Or am I misinterpreting what Firebug is telling me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes I was misinterpreting firebug. It turns out that firebug logs the url request and it looks like a normal request. However, if you monitor the network with a network monitor like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) you will notice that there are no outgoing packets to the url for the cached images. Flex does load the cached images.

Just to be safe on the image caching, I added a the following Cache-Control header (though I think the expires is enough. One year out at the time of posting this).

Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, must-revalidate

Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2011 16:00:00 GMT

So, if you set cache headers correctly (note that if the date is not a valid date in the expires header, it does not work), flex will load from cache when you call the url to a cached image.